# Which approach is "better" (in terms of optimization and complexity)

Tags: php

Suppose that whe have some object, derived from these class instances

```
class A
{
...
 private b //list of object of class B
}

class B
{
...
 private c //list of object of class C
}

class C
{
...
 private id
}
```

Now, somewhere in my code, I've got this situation

```
function findId(array $idList)
{
 [...]
}
```

Where I have to find (for each element of `$idList`) if an element is contained into this object "cascade"

## First solution

```
//object initialization
foreach($a->getB() as $b)
{
 foreach($b->getC() as $c)
 {
  foreach($idList as $id)
  {
   if($id == $c->getId())
   {
    //do something an break the cycle
   }
  }
 }
}
```

## Second Solution

```
//object initialization

$idSet = array();
foreach($a->getB() as $b)
{
 foreach($b->getC() as $c)
 {
  $idSet[] = $c->getId();
 }
}
$idSet = array_unique($idSet);

foreach($idList as $id)
{
 if(array_search($id,$idSet) !== false)
 {
  [...]
 }
}
```

Which is better? There are some alternative methods for reach my goal?

## IMPORTANT

There isn't better data representation. This because these objects are some database object (doctrine2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually combine the two approaches...

```
foreach($a->getB() as $b)
{
 foreach($b->getC() as $c)
 {
    if (in_array($id, $idList)) {
     ...
```

And if you absolutely can't optimize in a way you won't have inner loop, set the values of $idList as keys, and values as `true`, and use `isset()` instead of `in_array()`, since it's the fastest

Answer (score 0):

I would say that both are bad, they will in worst case give O(n^3), cause of the three for each loops. Is there maybe a better represenation of the data, in order to avoid all these loops?

If the answer is no, i would go with the first approach in order to avoid creating a new set.

Comment: No, there isn't a better representation. This because they are some database object (doctrine2).

Comment: ... why prefer first solution? Ok, you haven't a new set but you have to insert a nested cycle that will produce O(n^3) ...

Comment: Maybe `in_array` complexity is O(n) and, so, the second approach is worst than first?

Comment: Hmm, I dont which is worse to be honest, i do believe both will end up in O(n^3), but the first is more readable imo. But this is a highly selective opinion.